# Why is it that the LastWriteTime of a file and the stored Date&Time of that same file don't equal, even if are the same?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to notify users there has been a change to a file, by making a picturebox turn lime when the date in the application's settings is not equal to the LastWriteTime of a file. However, when i run the program and the two are equal (to my knowledge) it still says they are not equal. I've added a textbox in order to visualize it, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

My code:

```
fsw_wervelSTX_file = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("G:\divi\RATH\Applicaties\RSM\Program\Settings\IGART\WervelSTX\log_wervelSTX.txt")
    If Not My.Settings.fsw_wevelSTX_lastwrite = fsw_wervelSTX_file.LastWriteTime Then
        PictureBox_wervelSTX.BackColor = Color.Lime
        MsgBox("Time in My.Settings: " & My.Settings.fsw_wevelSTX_lastwrite & "  LastWriteTime: " & fsw_wervelSTX_file.LastWriteTime, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Else
        PictureBox_wervelSTX.BackColor = Color.Maroon
        MsgBox("It is the same", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If
```

There's a screenshot of the MsgBox in the link:
[MsgBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzsmZ.jpg)

The LastWriteTime is stored to My.Settings when the user clicks the button to open the specified file:

Code:

```
 Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
    Try
        Process.Start("G:\divi\RATH\Applicaties\RSM\Program\Settings\IGART\WervelSTX\log_wervelSTX.txt")
        PictureBox_wervelSTX.BackColor = Color.Maroon
        fsw_wervelSTX_file = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("G:\divi\RATH\Applicaties\RSM\Program\Settings\IGART\WervelSTX\log_wervelSTX.txt")
        MsgBox(fsw_wervelSTX_file.LastWriteTime, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        My.Settings.fsw_wevelSTX_lastwrite = fsw_wervelSTX_file.LastWriteTime
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error opening file: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going from the code you posted I guess it's a serialization thing. The datetime is probably stored in your settings as something like `2016-01-06 12:08:11` (aside the actual date formatting) whereas the actual datetime probably has more/better 'resolution' and contains something like `2016-01-06 12:08:11.123`. I'd suggest one of:

- Storing it in a specific (specified) format and make sure you compare no more than the actual stored 'resolution'
- Storing the value as ticks or some other specific long/integer value (e.g. UNIX timestamp for example)
- Allow for some 'margin' when comparing

Which is best is up to you and the requirements / usecases.

There's [all sorts](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-US?rq=site%3Ablogs.msdn.microsoft.com%2Foldnewthing&rn=oldnewthing&query=filetime) of weird things with file datetimes like [Why does the timestamp of a file increase by up to 2 seconds when I copy it to a USB thumb drive?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140903-00/?p=83) but my best guess currently is that you're just comparing two *slightly* different values.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Could you show me how to store it in a specified format? That'll be very helpful...

Comment: Never mind, I've got it to work thanks to your advice. I've posted my code adjustment for others to use.

Answer (score 0):

Added to load code:

```
 Dim timecompare As Date

Private Sub IGART_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            fsw_wervelSTX_file = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("G:\divi\RATH\Applicaties\RSM\Program\Settings\IGART\WervelSTX\log_wervelSTX.txt")
    timecompare = fsw_wervelSTX_file.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    If Not My.Settings.fsw_wevelSTX_lastwrite = timecompare Then
        PictureBox_wervelSTX.BackColor = Color.Lime
        MsgBox("Time in My.Settings: " & My.Settings.fsw_wevelSTX_lastwrite & "  LastWriteTime: " & fsw_wervelSTX_file.LastWriteTime, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Else
        PictureBox_wervelSTX.BackColor = Color.Maroon
        MsgBox("It is the same", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If
```

Added to button code:

```
Dim time As Date
Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
    Try
        Process.Start("G:\divi\RATH\Applicaties\RSM\Program\Settings\IGART\WervelSTX\log_wervelSTX.txt")
        PictureBox_wervelSTX.BackColor = Color.Maroon
        fsw_wervelSTX_file = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("G:\divi\RATH\Applicaties\RSM\Program\Settings\IGART\WervelSTX\log_wervelSTX.txt")
        MsgBox(fsw_wervelSTX_file.LastWriteTime, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        My.Settings.fsw_wevelSTX_lastwrite = fsw_wervelSTX_file.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error opening file: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```